# Reading a line from a file and parsing it in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, import, stack

I'm a student and learning C language. For my assignment, I have a txt file and I'm getting the commands from that, such as

```
    S X 11,156;21,234
```

the first 2 characters are directing me, and I don't have any problems with them, they will be solved with many switches.

The numbers are important, and I must stack them. Commas seperating the attributes and semicolons seperate the main elements. Like; first attribute of the first element is 11, the first attribute of the second element is 76 etc. I can put those attributes to 2 different stacks.

I will process the first attributes later, so the first attributes must be float type between 10-99. Second attributes are integers between 100-999.

The attributes will be given randomly and I don't know how many elements will be, but I'm sure there will be 20 elements max.

Structs are not allowed (I don't even know what they are), so I must create a stack with strings.

I'm new to "stack" concept, so I couldn't create it myself. So can you help me with creating a stack with these numbers?

(I searched the site many times but I couldn't find any matching questions.)

I tried to create 2 strings for attributes and used strncat functions to add the numbers but all I could do was get the numbers as '1', '1', '4' etc but it failed as I need those numbers as "11", "156" etc.. How can I get those numbers like that?

What I tried was;

```
    strncat (str1, row+x, 2);
    strncat (str2, row+x+2, 3);
    strcat (str1, ", ");
    strcat (str2, ", ");
```

Comment: **Structs are not allowed (I don't even know what they are), so I must create a stack with strings.** Where is the contradiction in that sentence. Besides what code have you wrote. ) makes a change from Sunday)

Comment: I didn't totally understand you (my english is not very good) but anyway, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, given this is a school assignment, people are not going to hand you the answers but can point you int the right direction.

There are a number of concepts here that you should have learnt or should learn to complete the assignment. Those are file and input handling, data structures (specifically the stack).

You should break these down and learn each one. You can learn about the stack data structure here [Stack (abstract data type)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29)

Comment: yeah this is a school assignment, I said that I'm a pupil at the beginning. And this is a little part of the assignment, not the whole of it. Anyway, I see your point.

Comment: Updated the question and narrowed my requests. Maybe you can help me now? :)

Comment: Ok, so back to the file and input handling, you can obviously read from the file so now you might want to look for answers on here and other places about string parsing. That should get you to the next step.

Comment: Ok, I have been looking for some answers again and "sscanf" seems useful but I couldn't find how to end the variable limit as; _sscanf ("S X %d,%d;&d............." &var1, &var2, &var3)_ etc but how can I understand if there is only 4 variables? or should I wrote max number of variables anyway?

Answer (score 0):

> I have been looking for some answers again and "sscanf" seems useful
>   but I couldn't find how to end the variable limit as; *sscanf ("S X
>   %d,%d;&d............." &var1, &var2, &var3)* etc but how can I
>   understand if there is only 4 variables? or should I wrote max number
>   of variables anyway?

Both ways are possible:

```
int a[20][2];   // max. 20 elements with 2 attributes
// scanf("S X");
for (nelem = 0; scanf("%d,%d", &a[nelem][0], &a[nelem][1]) == 2; )
{
    nelem++;    // We have read one more element's attributes
    if (getchar() != ';') break;
}
```

or

```
int a[20][2];   // max. 20 elements with 2 attributes
nelem =
  scanf("S X%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;"
           "%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d;%d,%d "
   , &a[ 0][0], &a[ 0][1], &a[ 1][0], &a[ 1][1], &a[ 2][0], &a[ 2][1], &a[ 3][0], &a[ 3][1]
   , &a[ 4][0], &a[ 4][1], &a[ 5][0], &a[ 5][1], &a[ 6][0], &a[ 6][1], &a[ 7][0], &a[ 7][1]
   , &a[ 8][0], &a[ 8][1], &a[ 9][0], &a[ 9][1], &a[10][0], &a[10][1], &a[11][0], &a[11][1]
   , &a[12][0], &a[12][1], &a[13][0], &a[13][1], &a[14][0], &a[14][1], &a[15][0], &a[15][1]
   , &a[16][0], &a[16][1], &a[17][0], &a[17][1], &a[18][0], &a[18][1], &a[19][0], &a[19][1]
       ) / 2;   // number of elements is half the number of attributes read
```